# Not displaying updated css - apache issue?

Tags: css, apache

I am a noob. 
I can't seem to update css on the server. I checked the file on the server, it's all updated, but the output keeps displaying the older file. Clearing cache doesn't help.
After researching through google, I found that I should EnableMMAP off and EnableSendfile off in apache config. Okay, I did that. It's still loading the older file when everything looks updated. 
Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Try 1) refreshing a page with Ctrl+F5 to reload all styles. 2) restarting you webserver (so that configuration changes took place) (But I seriously doubt that it's something with apache).

Comment: You should try to edit your html page to modify last modified date. This way, main page is newest than the one in cache, and then, your css should not be longer taken from cache either.

Comment: Can you view the stylesheet directly in the browser and then add a random querystring onto the end like ?q=123 to see if that helps retrieve the latest version ?

Comment: Okay, for some strange reason everything works now. Thanks guys!